# Positioning of Background Image is different in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am adding a footer to our organization's website. It looks just fine in Firefox (Mac and PC) and Safari (Mac). But, of course, not in IE 8.

I've got two divs (columns) on the left and middle and within them two rows of links. On the right side of the footer I have an image of our building I'd like to be flush to the top, right, and bottom.

In order to do that I had to make the image part of the background image of the footer. The footer is nestled within the larger content area and that content area has a margin or padding on the left and right sides. In addition, I wanted some extra space below the text so I added some padding (which prevents the image from sitting on the lower edge of the footer.

Here's the test page I am working on: http://americanart.si.edu/collections/index_footer.cfm

I'm stymied. Any fresh look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background is in the correct position, but your .col3 inside the footer is covering it. It has a grey background color and is 0px tall in smart browsers, but is rendering at 19px tall in IE even though it has no content. You should probably just remove that div if there is nothing in it.